# How to handle form data while switching between multiple frames

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have created a swing application in Netbeans environment. This application consists of four frames. Now my requirement is, after filling A frame when user clicks "Next" button then A's data should be buffered somewhere and then go to second form and so on. Finally when user lands in the last form, at this point i want the total data of all forms should be stored in database.

I am not sure how to achieve this. Can anyone suggest some useful resource or idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider having one non-GUI model class, that can be passed into the view (GUI) classes, either via a constructor parameter, or a setter parameter, i.e., `public void setModel(Model model)`. Then all views can have the same Model instance passed into them.

When the first window has its data "submitted", it submits it into the one shared model. If you're using a Model-View-Control structure, then this is usually done by the Control, but if your program is simple, a Model-View is probably all you need. The other windows can be notified by the Model of the changed data, and then change their displays accordingly.

---

But as an aside, also please ask yourself, how many professional applications do you use that jump from window to window? Not many because it is a very distracting and often unpleasant experience for the user. Most use a single main application window that swaps gui views within this window and with an occasional dialog window popping up when information is needed in a modal fashion. Please have a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)